# Tinymce - Event on set the carret inside textarea

Tags: tinymce, editor

Which is the event when you set the caret inside tinymce editor? For some reason, Click event works only for the first click. Is there any other event except click?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the focus `onActivate` event. For a full list of possible tinymce events check out [this page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api3%3aclass.tinymce.editor) and have a look on the right side of the page, there is a list.